# Can we use relational operator in select clause

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to make column in which my amount is less than certain value. When i try this, the query runs

```
select LOSA_APP.app_ref_no AS "App.Ref.No.",
   LOSA_EXP_SUMM_Z.group_exp AS "Group Exposure Amount",
   LOSA_EXP_SUMM_Z.group_exp - 25000 AS "Less than",
   columns AS "some Name"
   columns AS "some Name"
from 
     losa_app LOSA_APP
INNER JOIN
    code_branch CODE_BRANCH
ON
    LOSA_APP.attend_branch = CODE_BRANCH.branch_id
....
where 
    LOSA_APP.app_status in ('A','R')
and
    ....
 or 
 (
    '&&aplication' = 'Enhancement' 
    and 
    (
        nvl(LOSA_APP.review_type, '-') IN ('Enhancement', 'Additional')  and nvl(LOSA_APP.review_freq, '-') IN ('Enhancement', 'New')
    )
);
```

But when i change the line `LOSA_EXP_SUMM_Z.group_exp - 25000 AS "Less than"` to `LOSA_EXP_SUMM_Z.group_exp < 25000 AS "Less than"`, then i get the error that

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 34
```

line 3 is `LOSA_EXP_SUMM_Z.group_exp < 25000 AS "Less than"`. Why this runs when we use `subtract sign` and give error in case of `relational operator` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a relational operator in a `SELECT` then you will need to use it in a `CASE` statement similar to this:

```
select LOSA_APP.app_ref_no AS "App.Ref.No.",
   LOSA_EXP_SUMM_Z.group_exp AS "Group Exposure Amount",
   CASE 
        WHEN LOSA_EXP_SUMM_Z.group_exp < 25000 
        then 'true'
        else 'false' 
     end AS "Less than",
   columns AS "some Name"
   columns AS "some Name"
from losa_app LOSA_APP
INNER JOIN code_branch CODE_BRANCH
    ONLOSA_APP.attend_branch = CODE_BRANCH.branch_id
....
where  LOSA_APP.app_status in ('A','R')
and
    ....
 or 
 (
    '&&aplication' = 'Enhancement' 
    and 
    (
        nvl(LOSA_APP.review_type, '-') IN ('Enhancement', 'Additional')  and nvl(LOSA_APP.review_freq, '-') IN ('Enhancement', 'New')
    )
);
```

This will now return either a `true` or `false` if the record is less than 25000.  You can change the return to whatever you need, including:

```
select LOSA_APP.app_ref_no AS "App.Ref.No.",
   LOSA_EXP_SUMM_Z.group_exp AS "Group Exposure Amount",
   CASE WHEN LOSA_EXP_SUMM_Z.group_exp < 25000 
            then LOSA_EXP_SUMM_Z.group_exp - 25000
        else LOSA_EXP_SUMM_Z.group_exp end AS "Less than",
   columns AS "some Name"
   columns AS "some Name"
from losa_app LOSA_APP
INNER JOIN code_branch CODE_BRANCH
    ONLOSA_APP.attend_branch = CODE_BRANCH.branch_id
....
where  LOSA_APP.app_status in ('A','R')
and
    ....
 or 
 (
    '&&aplication' = 'Enhancement' 
    and 
    (
        nvl(LOSA_APP.review_type, '-') IN ('Enhancement', 'Additional')  and nvl(LOSA_APP.review_freq, '-') IN ('Enhancement', 'New')
    )
);
```